# Stretch text field with data overflow

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 9 text fields, I want to stretch all these text fields with data overflow. In my case, for all text fields I set position type to 'float' and I checked 'stretch with overflow'. And I put each row in Frame.

But I got a bad design, so I want to align the text fields relating to values 2 and 3 with the others texts fields.
Example : [enter link description here](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/661764overflow.png)

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved : 
I created Frame and group selected elements for each row.

```
<frame>
            <reportElement uuid="70cb42df-4e8f-4cbc-8d8f-f86a4aef9e3d" positionType="Float" x="119" y="233" width="332" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="4ca6a014-3eca-4c16-ae4e-079216b1e010" positionType="Float" x="119" y="253" width="332" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        </frame>
        <elementGroup>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b6102d47-3114-4673-a241-4dddb0e556bd" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="133" y="213" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["1"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="c22b46b5-e528-4bb5-ad1c-a5fca06faf38" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="383" y="213" width="55" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["value 1"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="66833d4b-1a6b-4398-9431-ed3ef80ef7dc" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="233" y="213" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["azertyuiop aaaaaaaaaaaaaaazeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrtttttttttttttttttttttpmmmmmmmmmmmmmlk"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </elementGroup>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="bc738f1d-150b-4959-9bc5-6a00b7112969" positionType="Float" x="119" y="213" width="332" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        </frame>
        <elementGroup>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="78d019fd-5e89-47f1-a895-9a4f0f754000" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="133" y="233" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5935ad61-77ec-4b05-84bf-6f72d3dcd0bd" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="233" y="233" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["DP-GI"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="83d4865c-f1af-4361-b6fd-9575a9835c7f" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="383" y="233" width="55" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["value 2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </elementGroup>
        <elementGroup>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="1a2694c6-974b-493a-b0a6-09b2be10f63a" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="133" y="253" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["3"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="450e7cce-5a49-4bbc-b502-d86352c7c873" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="233" y="253" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["AS-GE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="d8e7b402-0081-46ca-bd1c-2c3ae992b957" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="383" y="253" width="55" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["value 3"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </elementGroup>
```

Here is the result : [enter link description here](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/351540result.png)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an option to adjust the position of the text based on the fields in Left and Right. Also from your design, I can imagine that the Left and Right text boxes are inside List component or Table component.

Position of text boxes inside List or Table component cannot be adjusted based on the position of text boxes which are not inside the table or list component.

Posting a proper design or sample JRXML might be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: Tkanks for your answer, but the text fields aren't inside list component or table (I edited my post).

Comment: You mentioned that you have put each row in Frame. So is there three frames in your design?

Comment: Yes, I added new answer contains the solution. Thank you.